# How to stack a keyboard on flutter

Tags: keyboard, flutter, stack

Currently I have a listview of widgets and I stack a bottom button on the Top of the Stack to be always display. but when I tap on the textfield, the bottom button is push on the top, It's very ugly. How can I push the keyboard over the Button ?

thank you
[image]

here is a code example:

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
 }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return new Scaffold(
   appBar: new AppBar(
  ),
  body:   new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        new ListView(
      children: <Widget>[

            new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
  new Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),),
  new Card(
    child: new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter an address"),
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ),
   ),
              ],

            )
          ],
        ),
        new Align
          (
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,

          child :   new RaisedButton(
              child: new  Text("Button", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18.0,)),
              onPressed: (){
              },
              highlightElevation: 4.0,
              highlightColor  : Colors.white,
              shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0))
          ),
        ),
       ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend putting the "Button" on the Bottom outside of the Stack inside of a `floatingActionButton`.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
            elevation: 4.0,
            label: Text(Appliquer),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
floatingActionButtonLocation:
              FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
```

---

**EDIT AFTER CODE WAS ADDED:**
As I said in the comments I would use a FloatingActionButton/BottomNaviagtionBar or a Save-Icon in the AppBar

Here I added the FloatingActionButton to your code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(),
        body: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
          new ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(100.0),
                  ),
                  new Card(
                    child: new Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: new Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Expanded(
                            child: new TextField(
                              controller: _controller,
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Enter an address"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        icon: Icon(Icons.save), label: 
        new Text('Appliquer'), 
        onPressed: () { /*perform your Action here*/ },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Code is too long but structure is simple. I don't use bottom navigation bar or floating action button. Just I use Stack to show a List view on the second plan and a button on the first plan. and when I call keyboard the keyboard is call from the second plan, so he push the btton of the first plan with him.

Comment: I tested your code and this is the way a Stack works (for detailled info see Documentation). But I would still recommend to use a FloatingActionButton or a BottomNaviagtionBar for your purpose (guess it is to save your settings) or to use a save icon in the AppBar.